# Automation script for change password in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am working on automation script for change password functionality. I am getting test data from excel file. I have created test csript for positive scenario but now I have to verify if I enter wrong input, system is displaying excepted error messages or not for example:

- Enter wrong old password
- New password must be 6 character long
- New password and confirm new password must be same.

How I can verify these error messages in selenium. Do I need to create separate test case for each rule and use separate excel spreadsheet for each test case.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest method to achieve your goal is to attempt the unsuccessful login and then use the .getText() method to store the labels string, then run an assert against your expected text to ensure that they are a match.

Maybe a slight example to guide you on the correct path would be:

```
String actualIncorrectLogin = driver.findElement(By.id(YourIncorrectLoginLabel)).getText();
Assert.assertEquals(actualIncorrectLogin , expectedMessage);
```

You could also possibly use the .isDisplayed() method too, however the above is nice to ensure the text which is displayed is correct also

Answer (score 0):

On 'How I can verify these error messages in selenium.' There is something called getText() in selenium for elements.

On 'Do I need to create separate test case for each rule and use separate excel spreadsheet for each test case.' It depends but ideally onle one negative scenario is sufficient to validate the rules. You can get the text from web page and fetch the data(rules) from excel and compare the text vs rule as per your inputs.